# Hybris: Idle time sign out error

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I logged in to hybris application. after 30 minutes of idle time when I try to access User profile page it is asking to sign in but it is showing my username and Sign Out option. How to manage this session.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the session timeout ? Under your config folder, update all web.xml file of all extensions where you want to update the session timeout, and change the session-timeout :

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Also you might need to update :

default.session.timeout=(time in seconds)

Have you configured the remember-me ? what version of Hybris ?

Comment: `tomcat/conf/web.xml` just affects the underlying instance. In that case you'll need `ant customize` and a lot of configuration to align it with all deployment targets.

Answer (score 0):

This is the soft login feature implemented in the hybris.

This happens because of autologin feature. When session dies. Autologin filter creates new session according to rememberMe cookie.

RequireHardLoginBeforeControllerHandler looks for *acceleratorSecureGUID* in session, but session is newly created and it has no this attribute.

From the version 5.0.0,  the Accelerator Storefronts will support Remember Me Authentication (Soft Login) which will automatically log a customer into the storefront based on a cookie. This uses Spring's *TokenBasedRememberMeServices* implementation. Your own implementation only needs to redeclare the *rememberMeServices* bean to be integrated into the process.

Using Spring's Remember Me Authentication allows the Accelerator to make use of Role based authentcation tags, so for example certain links can be easily hidden or shown based on the user's login state.

A Remembered / Soft Logged In customer will need to provide their password and log in fully in order to access their Account or to proceed through Checkout.

Therefore, if you need to manage this, you will have to handle it via the RequireHardLoginBeforeControllerHandler or the rememberMeServices.

Hope this helps.

Comment: nope. but nice to see people talking about stuff i wrote